# java netbeans, why is my if statement always returning false

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this code and my if statement always returns false even though I entered the right inputs.

```
    boolean z = false;
    String x, y;

    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter x");
    x = cin.nextLine();

    System.out.println("enter y");
    y = cin.nextLine();

    if(x == "x" || y == "y") {
        z = true;
    }

    System.out.println(z);
    if (z) {
        System.out.println("successful");
    }
```

Comment: `String` comparison in Swing is done through `String#equals` or one of it's equivalent methods, not `==`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.equals()` to compare strings, using `==` will compare their references.

ex. `x.equals("x")`

Comment: ty so much, sorry for the duplicate, ill delete this now